# POST XMLHTTPRequest in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, post, xmlhttprequest

I'm not very familiar with APIs in general, but don't let that discourage you from answering this question ;)

I'm trying to pull data using the XMLHTTPRequest object. I was originally going to use a WSDL file, but the API I'm using does not have one. For some reason, when I'm trying to get the response displayed in an HTML file, nothing comes across, not even the error that it didn't connect. The api also requires the use of POST.

Here's the javascript:

```
    window.onload = function startCall() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "https://api.domain.com";
    var params = "Version=2.00&ApiKey=111111111111111111&CallID=001";
    http.open("POST", url, true);

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", "226");
    http.setRequestHeader("Host", "api.domain.com");

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send(params);

    function sendToHtml(url, 'target') {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) { 
        document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } 
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML=" Error:\n"+ req.status + "\n" +req.statusText;
    }
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="call.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<span onload="startCall" id="target">
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for any help

Comment: Are you passing the same origin policy?

Answer (score 0):

`POST` requests between domains are restricted so browser will not allow it.

There is option to enable it (`CORS`) by sending correct `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but it have to be done on API server.